# codeigniter escape function passes empty date to the table

Tags: codeigniter, escaping

I am using Codeigniter Escape() function when inserting data array to the table.
But it make date field empty when passing data through the escape function.
how to pass date through the escape()?
appreciate help :)

here is my view code which getting date and time

```
<input type="hidden" name="com_date1" value="  <?php echo date("Y-m-d"); ?>  ">
<input type="hidden" name="com_time" value="  <?php echo date("h:i"); ?>  ">
```

here is my controller code which assemble data array

```
$com_time_h = substr($com_time,0,2);
$com_time_m = substr($com_time,2,4);
$com_date_time = $com_date1.' '.$com_time_h.':'.$com_time_m.':'.'00' ;

$data=array('complaint_date'=>$com_date_time,
                'first_abuse'=> $reported_type_of_abuse,
                'final_abuse' => $actual_type_of_abuse,
                'no_victim' => $num_of_victims,
                'com_source' => $comp_source
            );
```

this is my model code which used escape().

```
$this->db->insert('tbl_case',$this->db->escape($data));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use escape function, use it for string values only. when you use escape for date it will add quotes to date like this `'2017-06-14 10:49:23'` and convert it into string.

So do escape on field level.

```
$data = array('complaint_date' => $com_date_time,
            'first_abuse' => $this->db->escape($reported_type_of_abuse),
            'final_abuse' => $this->db->escape($actual_type_of_abuse),
            'no_victim' => $this->db->escape($num_of_victims),
            'com_source' => $this->db->escape($comp_source)
        );
```

I hope this will fix your issue.

Comment: thanks it worked. i am using this function to prevent sql injection. is there any better way to do that?

Comment: @tharaka :Glad to help you out from this hurdles.